# Printing any value to web server with Flask

Tags: python, web, flask

My question is very simple, when you run this code :

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')

def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

You will see `Hello World!` on 127.0.0.1:5000

But I' m trying to change like this, I took `"Internal Server Error"`.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    a= 5+10
    return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Code Source: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#a-minimal-application

Comment: Change your last line to `app.run(debug=True)` in order to see the error details (trace, interactive shell, etc.). Post'em here if you still can't solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `hello_world` method should return a `str` or file-like object, but in this case you're returning an `int`. Just cast:

```
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    a = 5 + 10
    return str(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are still learning Flask, it would be a good idea to enable debug mode.

```
app.debug = True
app.run()
```

Or pass it as a parameter to run:

```
app.run(debug=True)
```

This way, you'll see more than just a 500 error.

Comment: Teaching him to catch fish is always a better option than giving him a fish. This is a better answer than mine.